# What is the purpose of these Visual Studio directories?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In what way are these directories used by Visual Studio?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
```

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019-12-27     20:24                10.0
d-----       2019-12-27     17:28                11.0
d-----       2020-01-14     08:34                15.0
d-----       2019-12-23     11:52                15.0_52fe5057
d-----       2020-03-24     11:10                15.0_6cf8de10
d-----       2019-12-31     10:10                15.0_6cf8de10Exp
d-----       2020-06-29     16:43                15.0_cffcaa9f
```

Comment: *All* applications are expected to store their data in the `AppData` folder.

Comment: The directories in Roaming can be replicated across machines on a network.  So that when you login on another machine, you'll get your preferred VS configuration back.  Like the window layout, keyboard mapping, server explorer view, etc.  This isn't documented anywhere afaik, it is all automagic.

Answer (score 0):

They are folders containing the various preferences of parts of the different versions of Visual Studio you have installed. Looking in mine (I only have VS2019 installed) and guessing based on filenames due to binary data; it contains: the window layouts of VS, Team Explorer previously-configured connection details, Activity logs, auto-recover project backup files, UI layout, and backup User settings.

Comment: Are these directories named with random hex values? Another developer has different names than I have.

Comment: Since it's in the roaming folder, it's likely a unique identifier for when you log in across multiple machines. Your coworker would have a different UID.